# Customizing the Named Entity Recogntition model in Azure ML

Tags: named-entity-recognition, text-analysis, azure-machine-learning-service

Can we customize the Named Entity Recognition (NER) model in Azure ML Studio with a separate training dataset? What I want to do is to find out non-English names from a text. (Training dataset includes the set of names that going to use for training)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this module's ability to perform NER with a custom set of entities is planned for the future, but not currently available.

If you're familiar with Python and willing to put in the extra footwork, you might consider using the [Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK)](http://www.nltk.org/). Sujit Pal has a [nice blog post](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2012/11/a-consumer-electronics-named-entity.html) and sample code describing the creation of a custom NER with that package. You may be able to train an NLTK NER model and apply it to your data of interest from within an Execute Python Script module on Azure ML.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. This is what I trying right now. I used 'openNLP' library of Apache with "Execute R script" module in R. Unfortunately the 'rJava' is not supported yet in AzureML sandbox (That means the R libraries that need JVM is not supported yet. Will try with NLTK.