# Custom entity recognition using Azure Text Analytics API?

Tags: azure, nlp, named-entity-recognition

Is is possible to define custom/special entities to be used for entity recognition within the Azure Text Analytics API?

NER (Names Entities Recognition) allows to discover a wide range of entities but for our purposes we're focusing on some model-specific entities (e.g. brand and product names) which we need to relate to the overall sentiment. General NER might not be enough for our purposes since we're looking for very specific appreciation/criticism terms during the topic generation.

The theme has already been presented in different flavors with no answers so far:

- in 2016 it seemed to be an "upcoming" feature: [Customizing the Named Entity Recogntition model in Azure ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071771/customizing-the-named-entity-recogntition-model-in-azure-ml)
- in 2018 someone was searching for much more specialized version capable to physically locate custom entities spatials position within documents: [Documentation / Examples for Custom Entity Detection (Azure NLP / Text Analytics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876142/documentation-examples-for-custom-entity-detection-azure-nlp-text-analytics)